# How To Get IEMI Number For Our Mobile Device?

Tags: android

Friends

How To Get IEMI Number For Our Mobile Device?

Plz Any Body Give This Ans.

Thanks For Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score -1):

[Google is your friend](http://www.technipages.com/android-find-imei-number.html)

1. Tap Settings from the Home screen.
2. Scroll toward the bottom and tap About phone.
3. Tap Status.
4. Scroll down and the IMEI number is listed there.

Comment: I think he meant "programatically"